# Ableton stores MIDI mappings but does not react to inputs

Tags: software, midi, ableton-live

I am trying to use my MIDI board ([Gordius LG2](http://www.gordius.be/midi-footcontroller-lg.php)) to control events in Ableton Live, but it doesn't react to my inputs.

Namely:

1. I edit the midi map
2. I see that the mappings are stored (they appear on the left window, in the list of mappings)
3. yet when I go back to mixer view, I push the switches, I see the midi icon flashing to indicate it's receiving midi messages, but nothing happens.

Does anyone have any idea why?

P.S. I am sending CC 4 for play and CC 6 for stop, that's all. I know Ableton doesn't like PCs, but I am not sending them.

Answer (score 3):

Open Preferences->Midi Sync. In the bottom half you have your input ports, with buttons for track, sync, and remote. To control Ableton midi maps, remote must be selected. You probably want to make sure the same device is *not* selected for a control surface in the top half of that screen as it's possible for them to both respond to the same message.

If you're on OS X, using Midi Patchbay 2 (free download) can also open up options as you can double an input into multiple ports by routing from your actual input into one or more IAC drivers and then use those in the Live.

Answer (score 0):

Verify the MIDI map list information, make sure you're transmitting the right channel. Make sure the remote switch setting for MIDI port is on, and, preferably, deactivate control surfaces for the port if any. Then try again